# In Quantum Physics would a camera count an observer that causes wave collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, measurement-problem, observers

Would the observation from a camera have the same effect on wave function as the observation from a living being?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an observer in quantum mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9857/)